# FileUploadException read timed out very long upload times on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Recently I got the problem. In one application I have got a form to which an user upload the file and then another one. (first ~3MB, second ~7.5MB). 
 The problem is that once the user upload the file and got the success screen but the file didn't upload the data on DB. I tried the same with the same file and got no errors, even changed settings in server.xml to connectionUploadTimeout=10 and, disableUploadTimeout=false but I cannot re-create the same exception (FileUploadExc). 
The obvious difference in logs is that my upload time is about 2 minutes. The client usually has the times below one minute but when this exceptions happens the upload time is above 10 minutes!
Here's the server.xml settings I think are important.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000" 
redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you doing upload? any frameworks used? check whether multipart form data attribute is present in your form tag(html).

Eg

without this tag you will get empty content.

check this

Comment: I use struts version 1.2 I recon. The problem won't be on the front-end side. The upload work normal and this is one time problem that happened with it. Another thing i changed in tomcat is connectionTimeout to 10 miliseconds but exception won't happen anyway and I don't know why.